# dependencies for pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

Do I need `sendkeys` and `ctypes` to be installed prior to installing `pywinauto` for python 2.7.1?

`ctypes` is already installed with python. Are there any other dependencies for `pywinauto`?

Answer (score 1):

The Docs are at http://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg/pywinauto/docs/index.html - but as I write this answer - I notice that they are slightly out of date (fixed the dependencies now :) - but not uploaded yet)

ctypes does not have to be installed (it comes with Python 2.5 and later).
sendkeys mis not necessary anymore - a pure python version is shipped with pywinauto. (https://bitbucket.org/markm/sendkeysctypes)

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  I installed a fresh python 2.7.3 and i had to download and install sendkeys before pywinauto setup.py would work.